# How to group by data using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of hashes that look like the below.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

rows = [{
          "version" : "v1",
          "timestamp" : "2013-06-04T06:00:00.000Z",
          "event" : {
            "campaign_id" : "cid2504649263",
            "country" : "AU",
            "region" : "Cairns",
            "impressions" : 3000
          }
        },
        {
          "version" : "v1",
          "timestamp" : "2013-06-04T06:00:00.000Z",
          "event" : {
            "campaign_id" : "cid2504649263",
            "country" : "AU",
            "region" : "Cairns",
            "impressions" : 3000
          }
        },

        {
          "version" : "v1",
          "timestamp" : "2013-06-04T07:00:00.000Z",
          "event" : {
            "campaign_id" : "cid2504649263",
            "country" : "AU",
            "region" : "Cairns",
            "impressions" : 3000
          }
        }
            ]

hash_data = []
for row in rows:
    ts = row['timestamp']
    meta = row['event']
    ts = datetime.datetime.strptime(ts,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z')
    meta['utcdt']=ts
    hash_data.append(meta)

data = pd.DataFrame(hash_data)
print data.values
grouped = data.groupby(['utcdt','campaign_id','region','country']).sum()
print grouped.values

[['cid2504649263' 'AU' 3000 'Cairns' datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 6, 0)]
 ['cid2504649263' 'AU' 3000 'Cairns' datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 6, 0)]
 ['cid2504649263' 'AU' 3000 'Cairns' datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 7, 0)]]
```

My issue is this.  I need to rollup data by time. Data should look like the below.  How do I do that in pandas?

```
[
 ['cid2504649263' 'AU' 6000 'Cairns' datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 6, 0)]
 ['cid2504649263' 'AU' 3000 'Cairns' datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 7, 0)]]
```

If use the below:

```
grouped = data.groupby(['utcdt','campaign_id','region','country']).sum()
print grouped.values

[[ 6000.]
 [ 3000.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
In [11]: data.drop_duplicates()
Out[11]:
     campaign_id country  impressions  region               utcdt
0  cid2504649263      AU         3000  Cairns 2013-06-04 06:00:00
2  cid2504649263      AU         3000  Cairns 2013-06-04 07:00:00
```

*As an aside, 0.11.1 will come with an experimental `read_json` function, which would create a DataFrame directly from json (file, url or string)...*

Answer (score 0):

Use the Pandas `DataFrame`, `data = DataFrame(rows)`, function first to efficiently organize your data. Then you can use `data.groupby(['timestamp'])` to 'roll your data up' by time.

[Here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-pandas/raw/master/lessons/01%20-%20Lesson.ipynb) is an interactive tutorial on how to use pandas.  An extensive tutorial list is located [here](https://bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-pandas). It will take you though all the basics easily and will let accomplish the analysis your looking to do.